# How to add Firebase Real time Database without adding google-service.json

Tags: android, firebase

How to add Firebase Real time Database without adding google-service.json to android Studio.

and

How to add More then One Projects of Firebase in android at a Time?

I Want To add Three Firebase Project Real time Database to one application in android studio?

Comment: You can't use firebase without adding `google-service.json`

Comment: Recently I show One Website Called **Kodular** in Witch We only Need Realtime URL and APIKey to Add Real Time Firebase Data base  and Make Application online Then why we cannot add Real Time Firebase Data base  in Android  only with URL and APIKey

Comment: Can you post that website link?

Comment: [link](https://creator.kodular.io/)

Comment: The question is, "How to read from..."?